# Xml: trying to put timeline on left with subject on right

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to put a time in a timeline on the left and some subject on the right. The time i get from the adapter and is should be no problem render it to xml. Its the format in xml that is a little complicated for me. In picture 2 you will see what i have allready, this is a grid layout.

(pic 1) Like this picture, but i will give what time from adapter.

(pic 2) This is what i have allready.

[image: timeline]
[image: phone]

I will let the code speak for it self.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notificationTitle"
        android:background="#33ccff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notificationTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/description"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="description"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/notificationTitle"
        android:background="#33ccff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/notificationTitle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timeOfMeal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    android:text="Time of Meal"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" /></LinearLayout>
```

Hope its help.